# What is the scope of TRANSACTION in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I was creating a stored procedure and I see some differences between my methodology and my colleague's.

I am using `SQL Server 2005`

1. My Stored procedure looks like this

   ```
   BEGIN TRAN
       BEGIN TRY
           INSERT INTO Tags.tblTopic 
               (Topic, TopicCode, Description)
               VALUES(@Topic, @TopicCode, @Description)

           INSERT INTO Tags.tblSubjectTopic
               (SubjectId, TopicId)
               VALUES(@SubjectId, @@IDENTITY)
         COMMIT TRAN
   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
           DECLARE @Error VARCHAR(1000)
           SET @Error= 'ERROR NO : '+ERROR_NUMBER() + ', LINE NO : '+ ERROR_LINE() + ', ERROR MESSAGE : '+ERROR_MESSAGE()
           PRINT @Error
           ROLLBACK TRAN
   END CATCH
   ```
2. And my colleague's way of writing looks like the below one

   ```
   BEGIN TRY
       BEGIN TRAN
           INSERT INTO Tags.tblTopic 
               (Topic, TopicCode, Description)
               VALUES(@Topic, @TopicCode, @Description)

           INSERT INTO Tags.tblSubjectTopic
               (SubjectId, TopicId)
               VALUES(@SubjectId, @@IDENTITY)
      COMMIT TRAN
   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
           DECLARE @Error VARCHAR(1000)
           SET @Error= 'ERROR NO : '+ERROR_NUMBER() + ', LINE NO : '+ ERROR_LINE() + ', ERROR MESSAGE : '+ERROR_MESSAGE()
           PRINT @Error
           ROLLBACK TRAN
   END CATCH
   ```

Here the only difference between the two methods is the position of `Begin TRAN`. 
According to me my colleague's method should not work when an exception occurs i.e. `Rollback` should not get executed because TRAN doesn't have scope in method 2. But when I tried to run both the methods, they were working in the same way.

In Method 1, scope of TRAN is outside of try block so it should be visible in both try block and catch block and should give result as per the scope methodology of programming works.

In Method 2, scope of TRAN is limited within Try block so `Commit` and `Rollback` should occur within the try block and should throw exception when a `Rollback` with no `Begin Tran` exists in catch block, but this is also working perfectly.

I am confused about how TRANSACTION works. Is it scope-free?

Comment: BTW, never and I mean never use @@identity. It will give you the wrong value if anyone ever adds a trigger onto the table that inserts into another table with an idnetity. Very poor practice even if you have no triggers now. This breaks data integrity and can be very hard to fix when it happens. Use scope_Identity() instead or the output clause in 2008. Further , best pactice is to immediately put this into a variable not use it inthe next statement. What happens in maintenance when someone adds a statment between those two?

Comment: @HLGEM thx I was getting this problem 6 month back. I knew triggers creates problem in this case but i had no alternative at tat time as i didn't knew that. thx again and +1 for this answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transactions are not "scoped" in the way that programming languages are.

Transactions are nested for the current connection. Each BEGIN TRAN starts a new transaction and this transaction ends whenever a COMMIT or ROLLBACK is called, it does not matter where in your stored proc this is.

Answer (score 2):

> Transactions are nested for the
>   current connection. Each BEGIN TRAN
>   starts a new transaction and this
>   transaction ends whenever a COMMIT or
>   ROLLBACK is called, it does not matter
>   where in your stored proc this is.

only to add that ROLLBACK ends "all" open transactions for the connection...

Comment: @ebis: could u be more xplanatory here. I didn't get exactly what u mean to say in last line.

Comment: BEGIN TRAN; .... Statements ... BEGIN TRY; BEGIN TRAN; ... STATEMENTS WITH Error ... COMMIT; -- this COMMIT will not be reached END TRY BEGIN CATCH; ROLLBACK; --Both Open Transaction will be rollbacked END CATCH; COMMIT; -- Tranlevel = 0, this COMMIT will although fail -- NOT nice if you have a Stack of PROCEUDRE-Calls, where each (or some) open a Transaction and one makes a ROLLBACK in the middle because of some error -- maybe its more clear, what I mean (probably not)